# Representing index rows as a range of values in 'pivot_table' of 'python pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, frequency-distribution

example data:

```
exdata = {'year':[1 ,2 ,5 ,7 ,2 ,3 ,2 ,4 ,8 ,9],
        'price':[120 ,99 ,55 ,23 ,87 ,31 ,149 ,45 ,32 ,55],
        'dist':[999 ,3741 ,8893 ,5321 ,1987 ,9299 ,573 ,4732 ,4536 ,4032],
        'loca':['a' ,'b' ,'a' ,'c' ,'d' ,'d' ,'a' ,'e' ,'c' ,'a']}
```

Using a pandas.pivot_table() to represent by 'price'

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['price'], values=['year','dist'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
```

[image]

I want to represent the 'price' axis as a range in the above table.
also want to express the number of each range.

In this case, if the option is available in the 'pd.pivot_table()'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe/47152692#47152692 check the link